# Drop rows from a dataframe based on other rows in the same dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
     date    | test_hour
------------+-----------
 2000-01-01 |         1
 2000-01-01 |         2
 2000-01-01 |         3
 2000-01-02 |         1
 2000-01-02 |         2
 2000-01-02 |         3
 2000-01-02 |         4
 2000-01-03 |         1
 2000-01-03 |         2
```

I need to drop all the dates missing test_hours= 1, 2, and 3. So the resultant dataframe should not include rows with `2000-01-03`, because it's missing `test_hour` = 3:

```
     date    | test_hour
------------+-----------
 2000-01-01 |         1
 2000-01-01 |         2
 2000-01-01 |         3
 2000-01-02 |         1
 2000-01-02 |         2
 2000-01-02 |         3
 2000-01-02 |         4
```

I am currently using a for loop to figure out which dates to drop, but that seems to defeat the purpose of using a dataframe. What a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way use `filter` with `isin` and `all`

```
df.groupby('date').filter(lambda x : pd.Series([1,2,3]).isin(x['test_hour']).all())
         date  test_hour
0  2000-01-01          1
1  2000-01-01          2
2  2000-01-01          3
3  2000-01-02          1
4  2000-01-02          2
5  2000-01-02          3
6  2000-01-02          4
```

Comment: Use a different `lambda`: `df.groupby('date').filter(lambda x: {1, 2, 3} <= {*x.test_hour})`

Answer (score 1):

#### `transform` and `lambda`

```
df[df.groupby('date').test_hour.transform(lambda x: {1, 2, 3} <= {*x})]
```

#### comprehension and `map`

```
df[df.date.map({k: {1, 2, 3} <= {*x} for k, x in df.groupby('date').test_hour})]
```

#### Slightly more esoteric version of `map`

```
df[[*map({k: {1, 2, 3} <= {*x} for k, x in df.groupby('date').test_hour}.get, df.date)]]
```

---

All yield

```
         date  test_hour
0  2000-01-01          1
1  2000-01-01          2
2  2000-01-01          3
3  2000-01-02          1
4  2000-01-02          2
5  2000-01-02          3
6  2000-01-02          4
```

Answer (score 0):

With `pandas-sets` library(https://github.com/Florents-Tselai/pandas-sets) and `transform` you can get pretty readable solution :

```
import pandas_sets
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date': ['2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2000-01-02'],
        'test_hour': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
        })

df = df[df.groupby('date').transform(set)['test_hour'].set.issuperset({1,2,3})]
```